# Add list of references in datamodelr

Tags: r

I'm trying to print a data model from two or more dataframes and for this I'm using the provided library [`datamodelr`](https://github.com/bergant/datamodelr#reverse-engineer-sql-server-database)

I'm using this two examples of dataframe:

```
DT1

       nombre  x networth       date lala
1:  david 22     1000 12-24-1997    3
2: ekstrm NA      900 15-10-1995    5
3:   alex 24      800  14-9-2000    6
4:  júlia 19     1300 14-09-2000    7
5: alvaro 30       NA 14-09-2000    8
6:      .  .       NA         NA   NA
7:   laia 40      500 09/14/2000   10
8:   lala 50      400 14/09/2000   12

DT2
         nota nombre
    1:  david     10
    2: ekstrm      9
    3:   alex     24
    4:  júlia     19
    5: alvaro     30
    6:   laia     40
    7:   lala     22
```

At the moment i can draw each table for each dataframe and i can define the relationship between them with the function `dm_add_references` using this few lines.

```
dm_f <- dm_from_data_frames(DT1, DT2)

dm_f <- dm_add_references(
  dm_f,

  DT1$nombre == DT2$nota,
  DT1$x == DT2$nombre
)
graph <- dm_create_graph(dm_f, rankdir = "BT", col_attr = c("column", "type"))
dm_render_graph(graph)
```

The problem appears when I try to make this references dinamically, for instance having a list of all this references between the columns, that I extracted before. I try this but it doesn't work:

```
a <- ""
c <- list("DT1$nombre == DT2$nota,", "DT1$x == DT2$nombre")
for(i in seq_along(c)) {
  a <- noquote(paste(a, c[i]))
}

dm_f <- dm_add_references(
  dm_f,

  a
)
```

> Error: Define references with logical expressions:
>              dataframe1$column1 == dataframe2$column2, ...

It will be really helpful if someone can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I have been able to create the references between a bunch of dataframes in a automatic way. I post here the solution hoping that it will be useful for someone.

There is another function called `dm_add_reference_` that can make one reference between two dataframes. The trick is that you can declare as many references as you want, calling this function iteratively.

```
dm_f <- dm_add_reference_(dm = dm_f, table="DT1", column="nombre", ref = "DT3", ref_col = "nombre")
dm_f <- dm_add_reference_(dm = dm_f, table="DT3", column="nombre", ref = "DT2", ref_col = "nota")
```

So taking that in mind with all the information that contains the relations between the dataframes stored in a list, I solve the problem doing this.

```
dm_f <- dm_from_data_frames(DT1, DT2, DT3)
for(i in 1:length(equalcols)) {
  dm_f <- dm_add_reference_(dm = dm_f, table=equalcols[[i]][[1]], column=equalcols[[i]][[3]], ref = equalcols[[i]][[2]], ref_col = equalcols[[i]][[4]])
}
```

where `equalcols` contains the needed information for all the references between each dataframe.